# How to use @types/geojson with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have successfully installed `@type/geojson` with npm.
Unfortunately, when using it in one of my NestJS entities, I am getting:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'geojson'
```

when running the app with:

```
npm run start:dev
```

My entity import code is:

```
...
import { Geometry, Point } from 'geojson';
@Entity()
....
```

`/node_modules/@types/geojson` does exist.

I have tried seeing Webpack doc: found nothing. Dev dependencies are ok.

Anyone has an idea that could help me?

Comment: Do you have `@types/geojson` in you `node_modules` ?

Comment: Module not found sounds like it's at runtime - do you have _only_ the types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `index.d.ts` file to the root of your project and make sure to reference it in the `include` array of your `tsconfig.json` file. There are a number of packages out there that require this type of explicit declaration which, in turn, makes their types/functions/etc available. In the case of `@types/gtag.js`, for example, the `gtag` namespace becomes globally accessible (no imports required) once it is declared in a root index.d.ts file.

here are the contents of my `index.d.ts` file for a project I currently have open

```
/// <reference types="@edge-runtime/types" />
/// <reference types="gtag.js" />
/// <reference types="react/next" />
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/server-only/index.js" />

declare module "react/next";
declare module "@edge-runtime/types";
declare module "gtag.js";

export declare global {
  interface Window {
    dataLayer?: object[];
  }
}
```

**important**

use the `types` reference for your triple slash directives whenever possible only falling back to an explicit `path` reference if necessary.

As mentioned above, `@types/gtag.js` is the package being referenced here (and there is no `gtag.js` package) -- if the package name begins with `@types/` then the `@types/` prefix is omitted in triple slash directive references.

for your situation, your `index.d.ts` file might look something like

```
/// <reference types="geojson" />

declare module "geojson";
```

after creating the `index.d.ts` file, referencing/declaring the package, and letting typescript know about the file via your tsconfig.json `include` array the problem should be resolved

*Update* -- tsconfig.json file for reference

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noStrictGenericChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts",
    "index.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```